# AWK string/substring manipulations loses original formatting

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, gawk

Hi I have the following file:

```
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.872000 0       1306.73 1000    1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.876000 0       1306.7  500     1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.877000 0       1306.7  500     1306.85 500     0       0       99
```

I want to change the timestamp in the second column ($2) and reduce it by 1 hour.

Im using awk, and split the 2nd field into 2 separate substrings, but when I use the following code:

```
awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,2)-1 substr($2,3,13),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}'
```

My output looks like this

```
P:TWS.XAUUSD 6:34:47.872000 0 1306.73 1000 1306.87 500 0 0 99
P:TWS.XAUUSD 6:34:47.876000 0 1306.7 500 1306.87 500 0 0 99
P:TWS.XAUUSD 6:34:47.877000 0 1306.7 500 1306.85 500 0 0 99
```

The calculation and information is correct, but I am losing the formatting (I require the hours HH column to be 2 digits).

How can i perform the same calculation and keep the original formatting.

I tried to use the *printf* command, but then I cannot seem to extract multiple fields, and get the whole line that I need.

> awk '{printf ("%02d\n"),$2-1}'

gives me the following output

```
06
06
06
```

How do I put the *print* and the *printf* together?

Comment: You don't need the substring operations to lose the formatting; the comma-separated list of fields in the `print` loses the inter-column formatting or spacing (only `$0` preserves it).  You'll be obliged to generate a single format string for `printf` with 11 appropriate conversion specifications, one for each of your output fields.

Comment: What if you have `0:20:40` and your script reduce one hour, should it become `23`???

Comment: Do you REALLY need to preserve the original formatting or do you just need the output fields to be tab-separated. The former is much harder to solve than the latter (just set `OFS="\t"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gawk-specific solution retaining the exact spacing of the original:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "16 2 72"}{printf("%s%02d%s\n", $1, ($2-1>0?$2-1:23), $3)}' file
```

The same thing could easily be done with substrings, of course.

Comment: @ooga Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for and it did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recomment using awk's time functions to do your time arithmetic:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { date = strftime("%Y %m %d", systime()) }
    {
        split($2, a, /[:.]/)
        t = mktime(date" "a[1]-1" "a[2]" "a[3])
        $2 = strftime("%T",t) "." a[4]
        print
    }
' file
```

This has the advantage, when the time is "00:00:00", of printing the time as "23:00:00" instead of "-1:00:00"

There are a couple of hours each year (the daylight saving transitions) where this overly simplistic arithmetic will give wrong results.

Comment: You might want to add that this requires GNU `awk` due to time functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OFS='\t'` (output field separator):

```
awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,2)-1 substr($2,3,13),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' OFS='\t' file
P:TWS.XAUUSD    6:34:47.872000  0   1306.73 1000    1306.87 500 0   0   99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    6:34:47.876000  0   1306.7  500 1306.87 500 0   0   99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    6:34:47.877000  0   1306.7  500 1306.85 500 0   0   99
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`, then:

```
$ cat file
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.872000 0       1306.73 1000    1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.876000 0       1306.7  500     1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    07:34:47.877000 0       1306.7  500     1306.85 500     0       0       99
```

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+)/sprintf "%02d", ($1-1>0?$1-1:23)/e' file
P:TWS.XAUUSD    06:34:47.872000 0       1306.73 1000    1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    06:34:47.876000 0       1306.7  500     1306.87 500     0       0       99
P:TWS.XAUUSD    06:34:47.877000 0       1306.7  500     1306.85 500     0       0       99
```

Comment: I'd recomment using the `DateTime` module for a perl solution. That will get the time arithmetic right.

Comment: @glennjackman I do appreciate your feedback and you certainly can use a module but it might be an over kill, since OP only has time to worry about. The only case the proposed solution would fail is when the time is mid-night. I have updated the solution to handle that case while maintaining the format which was OP's requirement. If you feel this could break on some scenarios please let me know and I will update the solution using a module `:)`.

Comment: It will also fail twice a year for DST. For example, in Canada/Eastern: `date -d "2014-03-23 03:30 - 1 hour" +%H:%M` is `01:30` -- so, to always be correct, just subtracting 1 is insufficient.

Comment: @glennjackman True but without dates you'd never know by just looking at the time. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also pipe the output to column command

```
[nabeel@nmoidu ~]$ awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,2)-1 substr($2,3,13),$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' test | column -t
P:TWS.XAUUSD  6:34:47.872000  0  1306.73  1000  1306.87  500  0  0  99
P:TWS.XAUUSD  6:34:47.876000  0  1306.7   500   1306.87  500  0  0  99
P:TWS.XAUUSD  6:34:47.877000  0  1306.7   500   1306.85  500  0  0  99
```